# buildozer - kivy+gspread+oauth2client app crashes on start

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer, gspread

After installing modules, I followed instructions to build an apk file. 
My app uses `gspread` and `oauth2client`. Put all the requirements in the `buildozer.spec` file.

I run

```
buildozer android debug deploy run logcat
```

then the application crash after loading screen.

The first thing I think the problem is it can't find `libpython3.5m.so`, `libpython3.6m.so`, `libpython3.7m`.
Here is the link for the log file.
[logcat record](http://www.mediafire.com/file/of2qg23a1jhnanm/log.txt/file)

Here is the link for the buildozer spec.
[buildozer.spec](http://www.mediafire.com/file/129d59jdb5w4w38/buildozer.spec/file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
02-11 14:04:06.022 16530 16664 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
02-11 14:04:06.022 16530 16664 I python  :    File "/home/kivy/Desktop/avac-app/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 11, in <module>
02-11 14:04:06.023 16530 16664 I python  :    File "/home/kivy/Desktop/avac-app/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/avacremote/oauth2client/service_account.py", line 26, in <module>
02-11 14:04:06.024 16530 16664 I python  :    File "/home/kivy/Desktop/avac-app/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/avacremote/oauth2client/crypt.py", line 23, in <module>
02-11 14:04:06.025 16530 16664 I python  :    File "/home/kivy/Desktop/avac-app/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/avacremote/oauth2client/_pure_python_crypt.py", line 22, in <module>
02-11 14:04:06.026 16530 16664 I python  :  ImportError: No module named pyasn1.codec.der
```

^^ this is the actual error in the logcat. Maybe you need to add pyasn1 to your requirements.

Comment: I see. Thanks you. I'm new to kivy so I still don't know how to check errors in logs. Thanks for showing me that. :D